# Django Forms - how to add the + sign for a Many2Many field

Tags: django, django-forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN6OW.png)Related to Django Forms and Many2Many

I have tried to look for ways to add the + to my django form when I want to add a new post to my webpage.

What I'm looking for is a similar function as the one in admin module. See picture.

I have tried to read though the docs but not sure what to look for. Have anybody build something similar?

my model looks like this

```
class Wine_taste(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = models.ManyToManyField('Wine_Category', verbose_name='Kind of Wine',related_name='wcategory')
subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Wine_SubCategory', verbose_name='Wine type',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
review = models.TextField()
producer_taste = models.ForeignKey('Wine_Producer', verbose_name='Producer or shipper', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True ) 
grape_taste = models.ManyToManyField('Wine_Grapes', verbose_name='Grapes') 
country_taste = models.ForeignKey('Wine_Country', verbose_name='Country of origin', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True ) 
sweetness = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LEVELRATE_CHOICES,  verbose_name='Rate Sweetness')
acid = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LEVELRATE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Rate acid level')
fruit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LEVELRATE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Rate fruitness')
taste = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Rate taste')
overall = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Overall rate')
thumbnail = models.ImageField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
featured = models.BooleanField()
previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('wine:wine-dyn', kwargs={"id": self.id})

def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('wine:wine-update', kwargs={"id": self.id})

def get_delete_url(self):
    return reverse('wine:wine-delete', kwargs={"id": self.id})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.thumbnail.path)
            
    if img.height > 400:
        new_height = 400
        new_width = new_height / img.height * img.width
        output_size = ((new_height, new_width))
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.thumbnail.path)
        
@property
def get_comments(self):
    return self.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')

@property
def comment_count(self):
    return Comment.objects.filter(post=self).count()

@property
def view_count(self):
    return PostView.objects.filter(post=self).count()
```

> Blockquote

this is my view:

```
def wine_detailed_create(request):
title = 'Create'
form = CreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
author = get_author(request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.author = author
        form.save()
        return redirect (reverse('wine:wine-dyn', kwargs={'id': form.instance.id}))
context = {
    'title': title,
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'wine/wine_create.html', context)
```

> and my forms:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Wine_taste
    fields = ('title',
              'country_taste',
              'category',
              'subcategory',
              'producer_taste',
              'grape_taste',
              'review',
              'thumbnail',
              'sweetness',
              'acid',
              'fruit',
              'taste',
              'overall',
              'featured',
              'previous_post',
              'next_post',)
```

> Blockquote

br
Lars

Comment: Show us what you have achieved so far, you need to provide some code and work from your side so we can help you.

Comment: add my own code.... please see the picture to see what functionality I need. Thanks